.net core 8 mvc development
I am developing a project in .net core 8 mvc, so i am encountering an error related to AppDbContext that says:
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message='AddDbContext' was called with configuration, but the context type 'AppDbContext' only declares a parameterless constructor. This means that the configuration passed to 'AddDbContext' will never be used. If configuration is passed to 'AddDbContext', then 'AppDbContext' should declare a constructor that accepts a DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> and must pass it to the base constructor for DbContext.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CheckContextConstructors[TContext]()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext[TContextService,TContextImplementation](IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Action`2 optionsAction, ServiceLifetime contextLifetime, ServiceLifetime optionsLifetime)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext[TContextService,TContextImplementation](IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Action`1 optionsAction, ServiceLifetime contextLifetime, ServiceLifetime optionsLifetime)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext[TContext](IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Action`1 optionsAction, ServiceLifetime contextLifetime, ServiceLifetime optionsLifetime)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\hp pc\source\repos\InvestmentProj\InvestmentProj\Program.cs:line 14


Could you please include relevant code snippet where this exception has been thrown? Hows your DbContext and program.cs looks like? According to the error message it seems the project is missing a constructor that accepts DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>. This constructor is required when you use AddDbContext in your Program.cs  to configure your DbContext.

This question is similar to: AddDbContext was called with configuration, but the context type 'MyContext' only declares a parameterless constructor?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi @Amna, have you tried the solution given? Do you still need any assistance on this, let me know if you have any further concern.


I am developing a project in .net core 8 mvc, so i am encountering an
error related to AppDbContext that says "'AddDbContext' was called
with configuration, but the context type 'AppDbContext' only declares
a parameterless constructor. This means that the configuration passed
to 'AddDbContext' will never be used. If configuration is passed to
'AddDbContext', then 'AppDbContext' should declare a constructor that
accepts a DbContextOptions and must pass it to the base
constructor for DbContext."

As per your error message its clearly stated that, your AppDbContext class in an ASP.NET Core application has only a parameterless constructor (a constructor that takes no arguments).
However, when you use AddDbContext to register your DbContext in the dependency injection (DI) system, you are passing a configuration for the DbContext (such as connection strings, database provider options, etc.)
So when defining DbContext with parameterized constructor and don't pass the argument into it or if you define DbContext without any parameter but trying to pass argument in either of the configuration would throws the exception you are getting.
So, in order to resolve this issue, you need an AddDbContext constructor with a DbContextOptions parameter to insert option dependencies. You can check here.
Let's have a look in practice, let's say, in your Program.cs, you are using the AddDbContext method and passing configuration options (connection string) for your DbContext. Like below:
  builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourDbConnectionString")));

For above configuration, your AppDbContext should define as following:
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

}


If the configuration doesn't align with your context defintaion in that case this exception might be thrown.
Note: If you look at the official document you would get more sample and explanation. If you need additional details, please check this document as well.
